# Fetch returns html source of the my own index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to use fetch in an react-create-app server(localhost:3000) to get a static .json file from my apache(localhost:80) but it returns source of my react index.html file!

Specifying port number results in "networking error"

```
const that=this;
fetch("localhost/myapp/data/structure.json").then((res)=> {return res.text()})
                .then(((data)=>{that.setState({structure: data})})).catch((e)=>{alert(e.toString())});
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: @Koralarts I'm sorry. I've added my fetch. Please ask for any additional info/code

Comment: server code? That is what is returning that right?

Comment: No this is inside a react components componentWillMount() lifecycle method. It is a static .json file. No server code is run.

Comment: `fetch("localhost/myapp/data/structure.json")` - is that the actual path you are using? Because that is a relative URL that refers to a path beginning with `localhost/myapp/data/` inside the current folder ...

Comment: yes. Ithink that might be the issue. Can you please tell me what URL would work?

Comment: Use relative path in order to get the JSON file you want, but first be sure that the file you are trying to access is on the right path, in this case, it should be the configured `path` for the dev server. generally from `react-create-app` is `public/` so here is where your JSON file should be placed.and you are getting your own `index.html` because the dev-server redirects everything to the `index.html` file

Comment: Yes that would work with this static file. But other parts of my backend are .php scripts.  Is there a URL to another local server? Or do I have to let go of nice react dev enviroment and move everything on apache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downright the problem comes to making react-create-app work with a local server which is explained in this guide https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/

In short I needed to put a proxy property with the value equal to address of my local server in my package.json. In my case:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:80"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a fully qualified URL:

```
const that=this;
fetch("http://localhost/myapp/data/structure.json").then((res)=> {return res.text()})
                .then(((data)=>{that.setState({structure: data})})).catch((e)=>{alert(e.toString())});
```

Note the `http://`

Comment: I get "TypeError: Failed to fetch" on chrome and "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." on firefox

Comment: Are you mixing http and https?

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I was calling `fetch("/path/to/some/api")` and getting this result. The problem was that `fetch` by default does not send authentication info in the request (in my case users are authenticated by a session cookie), and my API was rejecting the request and for some reason issuing a redirect to `/`.

The solution:

```js
window.fetch("/path/to/some/api", { credentials: true });
```

Also, what helped me debug the problem:

```js
window.fetch("/path/to/some/api", { redirect: "error" });
```

With the above, server calls which resulted in redirects were rejected.

Comment: Adding credentials: "include" did it for me instead of credentials: true according to docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options