# Why is fetch returning my React app's index.html instead of the URL I provided?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a fetch request in JavaScript. The goal is to get all the JSON from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/new/.json?count=25&after=) into my React app. I think I'm using one of the simplest methods available, but I'm still managing to mess up..

My expected result is a `console.log()` output with the json data. The result I'm getting instead is an error that says

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
>   position 0

In my exploration of the problem, I changed some of my code that says `.then(results => results.json())` to `.then(results => results.text())`. That shows me the text of whatever my fetch request is getting. I discovered it's not getting to the supplied URL at all, but instead is returning my app's homepage (index.html, located at "/", I think). Weird.

Here is the abridged version of my code:

```
import React from "react";

const hardcoded_url =
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/new/.json?count=25&after=";

getJSON = () => {
        fetch(this.hardcoded_url)
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
    };

render() {
    return (
        // <react stuff>
    )
}
```

What my `console.log(data)` prints out is literally the `index.html` of my React app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--- blah blah --->
</html>
```

I can even see the request go off in my Developer Tools network tab. To me, it doesn't look right. It registers as `undefined` and under `Network -> Headers -> General`:

> Request URL: http://localhost:3000/undefined
>   Request Method: GET
>    Status Code: 304 Not Modified

I've tried Googling the error messages and `javascript fetch url returns index.html`. The latter lead me to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852313/fetch-returns-html-source-of-the-my-own-index-html) which *looked* promising, but adding the "proxy" line to my package.json didn't help (Specifically, I added: `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"`). I also don't think it's a credentials problem because I can access the URL I'm after just from my browser.

I don't understand why this isn't working out for me. I'm copying the form of code from somebody else's github project for my own little Reddit clone. Theirs works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hardcoded_url` is a const and not the class variable. Accessing it by this.hardcoded_url is the issue.

`fetch(hardcoded_url)` is the correct way here.

`this.hardcoded_url is undefined` and so fetch is having `undefined` as the url considered relative the localhost and so API is http://localhost:3000/undefined instead of the actual url

Comment: Thanks I'm dumb, too used to writing "this.everything" after n days of studying React