# Vuejs Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 from express server

Tags: json, vue.js, express

Below is my Vue.js Code

```
        const load = async () => {
            try {
              // let data = await fetch(`127.0.0.1:4433/users/`, {
                //  // method: "GET",
                //  // headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
                // });

                // let data = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
                
                let data = await fetch(`127.0.0.1:4433/users`);
                console.log(data); //first checking if data is ok
                if (!data.ok) {
                    throw Error("No data hommes");
                }
                postsData.value = await data.json();
                console.log(postsData.value);
            } catch (err) {
                error.value = err.message;
                // console.log(error.value);
            }
        };

        load();
```

The Network Tab

[image]

my server.js config

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
```

the get route

```
const getUser = async (req, res) => {
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    res.type('json')


    const user = await buyer.find()
    res.status(200).json(user)
}
```

i added the `.set` & `.type` to try and force the response to be `application/json`

The code works just fine when making a request to the typicode server

i have gone through other similar questions but haven't found a solution

the server works just fine with postman & i've verified it's valid json

how do i configure the express server to not send `text/html` ?

EDIT

i have done a `postsData.value = await data.text();` instead & realized what's returned is the default `index.html` from Vue.

i have installed & used the cors express package

im thinking it's not even hitting the localhost server, how do i solve this?

Comment: what is your expected data?
could you show the postman API result?

Comment: @SepehrPourjozi thank you for your response. i have found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
let data = await fetch(`127.0.0.1:4433/users`);
```

the url has to be prefixed `http://`

that's the only change i have made & it has worked

found the answer here

[Fetch returns html source of the my own index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852313/fetch-returns-html-source-of-the-my-own-index-html)

i.e. the answer by @R.Tero